# How to manage versions of JMeter scripts

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, version-control, git

I have large amount of JMeter scripts which I store in Google Drive. I am planning to use a proper system that can help me keep track of changes and also manage their versions.

Which tool will be more suited for this Job. Is Git a good option or should I consider other tools? Moreover, do we have any best practices for version management of automation scripts?

Comment: I think Github would be a good option. Also you can setup SVN on your intranet for versioning and maintenance of the scripts. As far as best practices are considered, they are only what you make them! I don't think there is such a thing as one size fits all for that...

Comment: We have used SVN for a long time, and it's pretty effective for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should manage you automation scripts like you would any other code. If you use Git for source code management you should use Git to manage your Jmeter scripts as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `git` is a good option.

There is nothing like best, it's totally on you how you are implementing it. There are many other open source version control tools available you can consider:

- CVS
- SVN
- Mercurial
- Bazaar